# How can i send query string with html submit button to another page?

Tags: html, asp.net

I have this html code:

```
<input type="text" id="text1" placeholder="نام کاربری">
```

and this submit button:

```
    <button type="submit" id="login-button" Onclick="window.location.href='Handler1.ashx?username='"+text1+"'" >ورود</button>
```

but up href not send html text box value with query string and send empty value,what happen?how can i solve that?thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to call a function to set the url, rather than just reference the text box by id:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function setUrl() {
    window.location.href = 'Handler1.ashx?username=' + document.getElementById('text1').value;
};
</script>
<button type="submit" id="login-button" Onclick="setUrl(); return false;" >
```

Note: The return false is to prevent the button from submitting the form. A better solution would be to remove the `;return false;` and change the button type from `submit` to `button`.